# Form submit, doesn't call spring controller correctly

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I am submitting a form using jquery in my Spring mvc.

this is the jquery call to submit form.

```
    function uploadJqueryFormForEdit(documentId){
    alert("ccc");
    $('#result').html('');

   $("#editDocumentForm").ajaxForm({
    success:function(data) { 
        alert("ddd");
          $('#result').html(data);
          alert("eee");
          //getProjectSegment('documents','DocumentSegment',projectId);
            $('#editDocumentForm').remove();
     },
     error:function(e){ 
            alert(e.responseText);
            $("#msgDiv").html('Error');
        },   
     dataType:"text"
   }).submit();
}
```

And this is the form that I'm going to submit.

```
<form action="cont/uploadEdit?documentId=15&projectId=2" name="editDocumentForm" id="editDocumentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

When i'm using one parameter in action url, eg.

```
action="cont/uploadEdit?documentId=15"
```

it works fine. but when i'm using two parameters as

```
action="cont/uploadEdit?documentId=15&projectId=2"
```

it doesn't call to controller method correctly(not hitting that method at all)

here is the controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "cont/uploadEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public @ResponseBody String uploadEdit(@ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId,@RequestParam("documentId") int documentId,@RequestParam("projectId") int projectId,MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, UploadedFile fileDetail,UserBean userbean,Model model) throws SessionException { 
           logger.info("uploadEdit");
```

}

why can't I use two parameters in action tag.?

this is the controller method that worked fine with first action

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "cont/uploadEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public @ResponseBody String uploadEdit(@ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId,@RequestParam("documentId") int documentId,MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, UploadedFile fileDetail,UserBean userbean,Model model) throws SessionException { 
           logger.info("uploadEdit");
}
```

Comment: do you have a MultiPartResolver configured?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yes MultiPartResolver configured correctly. It works fine with one parameter.

Comment: Try yo send the data as , `data : $('#editDocumentForm').serialize() + "&par1=1&par2=2&par3=232"` and let me know.

Comment: I tested more than one request param and it works fine. I think your error is somewhere else. I suggest create a small project where you can reproduce the problem and [share it through github](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/12/how-to-upload-your-project-to-github/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error:

In the form that we are going to submit (in my case "editDocumentForm") there should be no any other input tags with the same name as in action url variables,

eg if there is something like this,

```
<input type="hidden" id="projectId" name="projectId" value="somevalue"/>
```

it will make conflicts. So make sure that no conflicts occur.

Answer (score 0):

Add `params = {"documentId", "projectId"}` attribute to the RequestMapping annotation

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cont/uploadEdit", params = {"documentId", "projectId"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
           public @ResponseBody String uploadEdit(@ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId,@RequestParam("documentId") int documentId,@RequestParam("projectId") int projectId,MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, UploadedFile fileDetail,UserBean userbean,Model model) throws SessionException { 
               logger.info("uploadEdit");
```

Comment: is it always necessary to do that ? wont it automatically figure that  since its attribute set has the requested values?

Comment: Actually it is to narrow the parameters to be processed. What I expect was, the second action call `action="cont/uploadEdit?documentId=15&projectId=2"` worked properly, but the first wouldn't. Since `required=false` definition isn't present as this way `@RequestParam(value = "projectId", required=false) int projectId`. For implicit definition of parameters, `params` is suggested.

Comment: @CahitGungor, actualy when it correctly works, controller method is different from above, I posted the controller method that doesn't work. Added the controller method worked correctly with one param.
edited the question.

Comment: Can you add `required=false` attribute as in `@RequestParam(value = "projectId", required=false) int projectId`.